# Как отключить аналоговые камеры на HikVision DS-7208HQHI-F1/N

Tags: видеонаблюдение

Сабж. Есть ли способ отключить камеры удалённо? Хоть через софт, хоть через веб-интерфейс. Физически отключать камеры нет возможности - регистратор находится далеко.

Comment: Что значит "отключить"? погасить порт и перестать принимать видеопоток с камеры, что ли? ну так разрегистрируй камеру, или установи неверные настройки камеры.

Comment: Разрегистрировать можно IP-камеры, а там аналоговые

Comment: Аналоговым можно установить неверный тип видеопотока.